# border-image property doesn't display border

Tags: html, css

I've followed the example off of [W3Schools here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_border-image)

HTML:

```
<h2 class="underline_red">Design</h2>
```

CSS:

```
.underline_red {
    border-image: url(../images/underline_red.jpg) 30 30 stretch;
    border: 15px solid transparent;
}
```

I've also included all the vendor prefixes even though the latest Chrome interprets it just fine.

I don't get any console errors, so my file is located and loaded no problem.

Unlike the example on W3Schools though, I'm not getting any border-image.

I'm obviously missing something

I've noticed the example on W3Schools doesn't use pixel sizes, I tried adding them but it didn't help.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Fvd9/)

Comment: Well, did you downloaded the border image and included in your project?

Comment: _"I've copy pasted the example off of W3Schools "_ Problem #1

Comment: @Vucko I'm using another image but yes. It's definitely loaded by the browser.

Comment: Try to add prefix for all browser

Comment: @j08691 I actually started by working on this from my CSS book. Then turned to copy pasting the example just to make sure I didn't do any typos, expecting their example to work. I don't usually copy-paste blindly :)

Comment: @JoffreyMaheo Did that :(

Comment: @Juicy can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Actually my comment was directed at using w3schools as a resource. They're not highly regarded.

Comment: @Vucko and others, added a JSFiddle

Comment: Remove `border: 15px solid transparent;` :)

Comment: @Vucko thanks I feel kind of stupid. I followed this here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_border-image and they set the border 15px transparent on all div, but I think it over-written by the subclass? Guessing if I put that line before the other it would have worked.

Comment: Yes, first you put `border-image`, and after you put for border to be `transparent`, so the first style gets _overriden_. If you inspect the  computed styles for `h2` you'll see that it has `-webkit-border-image:none`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flip the order of your styles:

```
.underline_red {
    border: 15px solid transparent;
    border-image: url(http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/border.png) 30 30 round;
}
```

#### [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8Fvd9/2/)

Comment: Thanks it was indeed the order. I think the first line is for Internet Explorer and it is then over-written by the following line for other browsers?

Comment: I'm not certain regarding different browsers, your best bet would be to test on different browsers and see the result.  The first line in this case does have an impact - if you adjust the size the border size will change...EDIT: Just noticed that you should keep `solid transparent` as it is indeed different across different browsers.

Comment: I think the issue is that `border` is a **shorthand** property and it resets **all** border properties **including** any individual ones that have been set previously. So, declaring it first solves the issue.